# Percent of done project

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, jprogressbar

I have an assignment regarding Java NIO and Thread. I should write a program with these four important abilities: copy, cut, rename, and delete. I made 4 classes for each part of project. All of them extend `Runnable` and in the run I used some code like this:

```
fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.showOpenDialog(Copy.this);
File f1 = fc.getSelectedFile();
fc.showOpenDialog(Copy.this);
File f2 = fc.getSelectedFile();
if(copyFile(f1, f2)){
    System.out.println("File Copied");
}
```

`fc` is a `JFileChooser` class field and I have a `mainFrame` that have 4 buttons and each one starts a threat from each class. I do not know about my way and I have no idea what it should be like. I've watched two videos about multi-threading and I have no idea how this program can be a deadlock or how it can have problems running, and my biggest problem is that I want to have `JProgressBar` in file copying, file deleting and file cutting and I have no idea about how can I know about these levels in the program to do the best with `JProgressBar`.
it is the whole project : https://www.mediafire.com/?yyw8jg1xncfp2xn

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Do you need to know how to start new threads in java? How to copy a file? How to delete a file? How to truncate a file?

Comment: my main functions do correctly. I have problem with JProgressBar, this program will be tested in different conditions, so do you know about problems may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the values needed to update your `JProgressBar` the simplest way would be to have a thread monitor the size of your target files and compare them against the original. you could do this with `f1.length()` and `f2.length()`. by comparing these 2 values, you would be able to determine the status of the current action whether it is deleting, copying, or truncating the size of a file. alternatively, you would need to have a handle to your `JProgressBar` within each of your functions such as `copyFile(...)` and from there you could update the progress bar based on the iteration within the loop. For a more detailed answer, I would need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, Thank you, I uploaded the whole project: https://www.mediafire.com/?yyw8jg1xncfp2xn